# create "not legible" file .bin in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

***Hey guys.***

I'm developing a program that needs a password to acess.

I'm using for now a file .bin with the password and when i want to execute the program, it'll check the file and compare my entry with the actual password registered.

But soon i discovered that i could just open the .bin with notepad and it'd give me the **secret** password.

So i'm wondering if there's a way to create the file (it can be .txt or .dat as well) that can't be read using notepad or similar programs.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The simplest way would be to encode your data in some way, like [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html).  This would prevent casual changes. It's still not very secure though.

Comment: i thought of something like this, but i really wanted make it a much more secure

Comment: The problem is this: if you encrypt the file solely with information on the machine, there isn't really a way to avoid saving that encryption key as plaintext somewhere on the machine.  What you could do is have a lock file that is some secret that your code requires to operate.  You can then encrypt that with the password, so that it requires the password to unlock it.  Then the password is not stored anywhere on the machine, so your attacker cannot alter it.  This has its own challenges, however.

Comment: well, i'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: Do not store the plaintext password in the file.  Instead store a salted cryptographic hash of the password.  To validate a password entry, repeat the salted hash computation on the input string and check that the result matches the content of the file. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 for details.  With this approach it doesn't matter if the file is readable; knowing the content of the file does not allow an attacker to discover the password.

Comment: that's a good idea, i'll research about this and probably (by the little things that i saw about it) i'll be using this, thanks

Comment: well, i studied it and implemented it. it's working greatly and i thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

### solution - pbkdf2

Well, thanks to *ottomeister* i came across with the pbkdf2 (you can find it here: https://github.com/dlitz/python-pbkdf2).

The hash solution worked and if anyone wants more details the github link should be enough.